# Signed release apk locally transfered can't be installed?

Tags: android

Experts,

I have a signed release android apk generated locally in my android studio. I have copied it to my mobile device & tried to install it. But every time it says "App not installed" error.

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Delete previous version of app on device?

Comment: Please elaborate your question. Without the proper description nothing can be solved.

Comment: what exactly error you get?

Comment: error is - "app not installed"

Comment: error is gone now, thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bet - you have used the same device for installing app directly from Adnroid Studio during development process. If so - you got your application installed with debug key. And the problem is - you can't install app with release key above debug key - OS will throw you "Semantic process error" (or something like that) if you try. You have to delete your app manually and after try to install again with release apk.

Comment: you are right. I will uninstall the old ones & try fresh.

Comment: error is gone, thanks